# How to get the data of a recycler item in a recycler adapter from firebase onClick?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have an app that displays Cardviews in a recycler adapter. Each cardview gets its data from Firebase. My app shows classes a user can sign up for and I want the user to be able to click on the cardview, with the class they want, and save it under their UID.

Here is my code of the activity that shows English classes:

```
 private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private List<Listdata> list;
private RecyclerView recyclerview;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_english_classes);
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rview);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("English");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            list = new ArrayList<>();
           // String key = myRef.child("English").push().getKey();
           // System.out.println(key);
            // StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Class_model new_class = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Class_model.class);
                String nameofclass = new_class.getDate_clasname();
                String teacherofclass = new_class.getTeacher();
                String roomnumberofclass = new_class.getRoom_number();
                Listdata listdata = new Listdata(nameofclass, teacherofclass, roomnumberofclass);
                //String name = userdetails.getName();
                //String email = userdetails.getEmail();
                //String address = userdetails.getAddress();
                listdata.setDate_class(nameofclass);
                listdata.setTeacher(teacherofclass);
                listdata.setRnumber(roomnumberofclass);
                list.add(listdata);
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            RecyclerviewAdapter recycler = new RecyclerviewAdapter(list);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(English_classes.this);
            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
            recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(English_classes.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check your connection! If, problem persists please email svhsdev@vigoschools.org!");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
            // Failed to read value
            //  Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });

}
//});
```

Here is the code for my Recycler Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.MyHolder>{

List<Listdata> listdata;

public RecyclerviewAdapter(List<Listdata> listdata) {
    this.listdata = listdata;
}

@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_class_model,parent,false);

    MyHolder myHolder = new MyHolder(view);
    return myHolder;
}


public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    Listdata data = listdata.get(position);
    holder.vdate_class.setText(data.getDate_class());
    holder.vteacher.setText(data.getTeacher());
    holder.vrnumber.setText(data.getRnumber());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listdata.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView vdate_class , vteacher,vrnumber;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vdate_class = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_class_name);
        vteacher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.room_number);
       vrnumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher);

           }
       }

    }
```

Here is my code for the Class model class:

```
public class Class_model {

String date_clasname;
String  teacher;
String room_number;
public Class_model(){};
public Class_model(String date_cname, String teach, String room_n){
    //subject = subject2;
    date_clasname = date_cname;
    teacher = teach;
    room_number = room_n;

}

public String getDate_clasname() {
    return date_clasname;
}

public void setDate_clasname(String date_clasname) {
    this.date_clasname = date_clasname;
}

public String getTeacher() {
    return teacher;
}

public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
    this.teacher = teacher;
}

public String getRoom_number() {
    return room_number;
}

public void setRoom_number(String room_number) {
    this.room_number = room_number;
}
```

}

Here is my code for the List Data class:

```
public class Listdata {

public String date_class;
public String teacher;
public String rnumber;

public Listdata(String date_class, String teacher, String rnumber) {
    this.date_class = date_class;
    this.teacher = teacher;
    this.rnumber = rnumber;
}

public String getDate_class() {
    return date_class;
}

public void setDate_class(String date_class) {
    this.date_class = date_class;
}

public String getTeacher() {
    return teacher;
}

public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
    this.teacher = teacher;
}

public String getRnumber() {
    return rnumber;
}

public void setRnumber(String rnumber) {
    this.rnumber = rnumber;
}
```

}

Here is my database structure:

```
{
"English" : {
"-Lgxm2KJPDbQG3C0flA2" : {
  "date_clasname" : "english",
  "room_number" : "d",
  "teacher" : "f"
  }
 },
  "Users" : {
   "NnJlSVeqGXhJ2Nab2bhjr0HIpku2" : {
    "Classes" : {
    "-Lh1YFTY9L8XXZMMOHDb" : {
      "date_clasname" : "ggh",
      "room_number" : "hhh",
      "teacher" : "uu"
    },
  "email" : "samuelford48@gmail.com",
  "grade" : "12",
  "name" : "Samuel Ford"
},
"cCEPKCKP99cnNZHxsktTBtOrG5Y2" : {
  "Classes" : {
    "-Lh1e_Rj9LBn6tkheIqO" : {
      "date_clasname" : "gg",
      "room_number" : "njgt",
      "teacher" : "gg"
    }
  },
  "email" : "matthewford48@gmail.com",
  "grade" : "12",
  "name" : "Matthew"
},
"zEEYIiWC3NXKa1adlChVtbxBML92" : {
  "Classes" : {
    "-Lh1b7UnsnNIA4BDDCv_" : {
      "date_clasname" : "bb",
      "room_number" : "bb",
      "teacher" : "hb"
    }
  },
  "email" : "svhsdev@vigoschools.org",
  "grade" : "77",
  "name" : "sa"
     }
   }
 }
```

In essence, I want the user to be able to click on the english class displayed in the recycler adapter and add it to there list of classes which is under their uid. I don't have a problem with my code...I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Do you have an error? Please add your database strucrure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't have an error... I just don't know how to add the class the user clicks on to the user's uid. I added the database structure. Thanks!

Comment: Not the best option to add on click listener on every holder but have you tried Israel dela Cruz's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a click listener to your holder itemView, or the cardView in that itemView.

In you adapter.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    Listdata data = listdata.get(position);
    holder.vdate_class.setText(data.getDate_class());
    holder.vteacher.setText(data.getTeacher());
    holder.vrnumber.setText(data.getRnumber());

    // @HERE
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        void onClick(View v) {
            // Do your stuff here with your data
        }
    });
}
```